# How to get the IMEI number of a lost phone?

Tags: lost-phone, imei

I lost my Android phone Vivo 1713 (v5s) recently. I don't know its IMEI number. How do I get it?

Comment: I believe IMEI is a unique number given. No one can tell yours unless you modify it for other purposes

Answer (score 1):

Login to the "[Find my Device](https://www.google.com/android/find)" page with your Google Account that was used on your phone. Your phone should be listed. Click the "!" button to see the IMEI number of the phone. You should see something like this:
[image: IMEI photo in Google Device anager]